# Can I run Package Manager Console from my code?

Tags: ef-code-first, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I'm using Code First Migrations, it required run commands from Package Manager Console to update model. I want to run it from my code:

Example: ExcuteCommand("Update-Package"). Could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can execute the Update-Package command as it is a PowerShell script which can be executed from C#. You can find a good description here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

However what you is looking for is not running the update command from the code but updating the database from the code which could be better achieved by using the DbMigrator class like this:

```
var migrationsConfiguration = new Configuration();
migrationsConfiguration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(
    "Server=TestServer;Database=TestDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;",
    "System.Data.SqlClient");

var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(migrationsConfiguration);
dbMigrator.Update();
```

Comment: okay, I hope it works, but if there is any problem just ask it here :)